# how to create triangular button in c#

Tags: c#-3.0

How to create Custom shaped buttons in c#: say triangular

Comment: Is this using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @Will: Did you mean "non-rectangular buttons"?

Comment: @frustrated thems too.  Big bowls of tears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pictureBox as a button.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to set a tringular image on the button, with transparent areas outside the triangle.

As others have suggested, you could also use a PictureBox object as a button and handle the "click" even of it.

Another way is probably to write a TriangleButton class that extends the Button class, then override the Paint method so that you can draw a triangle instead of the regular button shape. Not sure how to handle the "click" areas of the button (you might still have a a rectangular click region).

Answer (score 0):

You create a rectangular ImageButton with a transparent background.